# How to implement a Terms of Service page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to figure out how to implement a terms of service page. The purpose is to have a checkbox that if it not checked, the user wont be able to navigate to any other page by just typing another page url in the address bar.

I tried storing a TOSNotChecked session variable but that has not worked well so far.

I also tried having a redirect in the Global.asax but it will get stuck in a loop.

Anyone has a fool proof way to implement this.

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest storing the data in a database table. Depending on how many users you have would affect the type of storage. If they are logged in and agree, then it would be simple to have that be somewhere in their profile table.

However, it seems to me you are asking people who are not authenticated to agree to a ToS which would mean that you may need a different approach. I think that when they agree there should be a variable stored inside of the Session with a GUID and perhaps their IP address. Then, inside a cookie on their machine, store a mirror of that. If they match up, then they have agreed to the ToS.

Answer (score 0):

by checking on the "not checked" status you're basically testing for something that isn't there which can always be problematic.  Approach it from the other end and store an "Is Checked" session variable and test for that before letting them on.

You can also store this in the database and check on login to the site and if it isn't present then fail the login authentication and with no authentication block access to the rest of the site.